# Should I put HR system and various business related systems under SSO?

Tags: web-application, sso

We are building several systems for businesses, like employees schedule management and sharing, customer management and recently we are building HR System.
We have put Schedule management and customer/contacts management application under SSO. Is it safe and meaningful to put HR System also under the same SSO system?

Comment: A question that's common here: "safe from what?" What is your concern?

Comment: @schroeder is on to something. you are mixing functional requirements with security risk without having a threat assessment.